# How to get dropdown button to work in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

How do I get the drop-down button to work within a card in React?

I am building in react and using Tailwind css card to display API information. I do not want to show all the info at once so plan to use a dropdown to say "show more" but somehow it won't work.
Button shows but when clicked nothing happens. Here is the code below, this also applies to dropdown code from the tailwind official website so something wrong with my app that I cannot figure out.

You can see the code display [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/fou5shIEmm)

Thank you

```
    <h5 class="text-gray-900 text-xl leading-tight font-medium mb-2">Card title</h5>
    <p class="text-gray-700 text-base mb-4">
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
      content.
    </p>
    <button
        class="dropdown-toggle inline-block px-6 py-2.5 bg-purple-600 text-white font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-purple-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-purple-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-purple-800 active:shadow-lg active:text-white transition duration-150 ease-in-out flex items-center whitespace-nowrap"
        type="button"
        id="dropdownMenuButton2"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="false"
      >
        SHOW MORE
        <svg
          aria-hidden="true"
          focusable="false"
          data-prefix="fas"
          data-icon="caret-down"
          class="w-2 ml-2"
          role="img"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 320 512"
        >
          <path
            fill="currentColor"
            d="M31.3 192h257.3c17.8 0 26.7 21.5 14.1 34.1L174.1 354.8c-7.8 7.8-20.5 7.8-28.3 0L17.2 226.1C4.6 213.5 13.5 192 31.3 192z"
          ></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
      <ul
        class="dropdown-menu min-w-max absolute hidden bg-white text-base z-50 float-left py-2 list-none text-left rounded-lg shadow-lg mt-1 hidden m-0 bg-clip-padding border-none bg-gray-800"
        aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2"
      >
        <h6
          class="text-gray-400 font-semibold text-sm py-2 px-4 block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent"
        >
          Dropdown header
        </h6>
        <span
          class="text-sm py-2 px-4 font-normal block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent text-gray-300"
          >Dropdown item text</span
        >
        <li>
          <a
            class="dropdown-item text-sm py-2 px-4 font-normal block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 active:bg-blue-600"
            href="#"
            >Action</a
          >
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            class="dropdown-item text-sm py-2 px-4 font-normal block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700"
            href="#"
            >Another action</a
          >
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            class="dropdown-item text-sm py-2 px-4 font-normal block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700"
            href="#"
            >Something else here</a
          >
        </li>
        <li><hr class="h-0 my-2 border border-solid border-t-0 border-gray-300 opacity-25" /></li>
        <li>
          <a
            class="dropdown-item text-sm py-2 px-4 font-normal block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700"
            href="#"
            >Separated link</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your `"show more"` button ? I can't see it and where is you API data ?

Comment: you do not have a click handler on the button

Comment: edited button title

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `hidden` class from `ul` tag and you can use one of component library like [flowbite](https://flowbite.com/) or [daisyui](https://daisyui.com/)

Comment: You need to use js if you want to create dropdown with `ul` and `li` tag